# Is there a standardized platform agnostic URL scheme to encode a geolocation?

Tags: html, geolocation, encoding, url

Are there platform-agnostic URL Schemes like the *geo URI scheme* (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geo_URI_scheme) that are supported across all the major OSs and browsers?

PS: I came across the geo URI scheme while researching ways to publish geolocations on the web but the URIs encoded in this URI scheme are currently unsupported by most of the platforms (Tested using Google Chrome on MacOS). I would prefer if the URI scheme is platform-agnostic, unlike the Google Maps Location URL or the OpenStreetMaps Location URL.